# Последний сегмент из строки

Tags: php, laravel, строки, разделение-строк

Сайт на Ларавел, не знаю версии.

Есть такая функция:

```
 /**
     * Get the [parent_url] column value.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getParentUrl()
    {
        return $this->parent_url;
    }
```

где parent_url - значение из ячейки БД.

В шаблоне вывожу это значение так: `$model->getParentUrl()`

Но проблема в том, что в ячейке parent_url пишется, например: zvuk/vch-draiveri, то есть родительская категория/подкатегория. И в шаблоне соответственно выводится zvuk/vch-draiveri, есть ли возможность в шаблоне выводить только последний сегмент, а именно vch-draiveri?

Может создать отдельную функцию, которая будет сегментировать и выдавать только последний сегмент?
Но я в PHP - 0, знатоки хелп...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если blade-шаблон то выводите как-то так

```
{{ basename($model->getParentUrl()) }}
```

Comment: Супер!!! Спасибо, сработало))